# Evaluate $\oint_{C} (\cos x e^x + y)dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let $C$ be the curve parameterized by $r(t)=(5+2 \cos t, 2 \sin t)$   for $0≤t≤2π$. I'm trying to evaluate $\oint_{C} (\cos x e^x + y)dx$ over this region.

I tried to use Green's Theorem to solve this:

$$\int (\cos x e^x + y)dx$$

$$=\iint\bigg(\frac{\partial(0)}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial(\cos (x) e^x + y)}{\partial y}\bigg)dxdy$$

$$=\iint(0-1)dxdy$$

$$=- \iint dxdy$$

However, I'm getting stuck on the bounds of this integral now and how to express the curve $C$. I know the curve is an ellipse, but I'm having trouble representing it in either Cartesian or polar coordinates. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: it's a circle

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much - I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I'm getting stuck on the bounds of this integral now and how to express the curve C. I know the curve is an ellipse, but I'm having trouble representing it in either Cartesian or polar coordinates. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

$$r(t)=(5+2 \cos t, 2 \sin t)$$

Well here is the deal, since we are dealing in cartesian components $r(t) = <x,y>$ , by equating vector components we have:

$$ x = 5 + 2 \cos t$$
$$ y = 2 \sin t$$

Now, to recover the region, we need the cartesian curve of the domain, we can manipulate the above pairs of equation to remove the $t$ parameter dependence. This gives a circle.

---

### Change of variables?

$$ x-5 = r \cos \theta$$

$$ y= r \sin \theta$$

We can use the above relation on the original set of two equations in cartesian with paramter to get:

$$ 2 \cos t = r \cos \theta \tag{1}$$

$$ 2 \sin t =r \sin \theta \tag{2}$$

Square and add the two equations above:

$$ 4 = r^2$$

By division we see $\tan t = \tan \theta$ , we can find that $\theta$ can take anything from $  \left[ 0 , 2 \pi \right]$. Now, we just need to find the area element, this we can do by Jacobian/ Differential forms.

$$ dx dy = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \\ \end{vmatrix} dr d \theta= r^2 dr d \theta$$ from  (1) and (2).

Our integral now is:

$$ \int \int r^2 dr d \theta$$

And our domain is the region enclosed in $r^2 = 4 $, which is $r<2$ and $ 0 < \theta < 2 \pi$. Since each of these variables  are seperable, we have the integral:

$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} d \theta \int_0^2 r^2 dr$$

Comment: The last step is just multriplication of rael numbers